# How can I have an Original sized View without compressing in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to make a HStack which has some Text inside, if this Text get more and more HStack would compress Texts to fit all inside the HStack, for preventing compressing I add a GeometryReader, but it does not help, the HStack is compressing Text, what is wrong with my code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOTBR.png)

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        


        GeometryReader { geometry in

                HStack(spacing: 25) {

                    ForEach(0..<10, id:\.self) { index in
                            Text("text " + index.description)
                    }
   
                }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make text fixed size, like

```
ForEach(0..<10, id:\.self) { index in
        Text("text " + index.description)
          .fixedSize()
}
```

Comment: thanks, then I do not need geometry reader for that, right?

Comment: If you are not going to use any GeometryReader properties, then you don't need it.